# How to get data from xm file with id using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a simple XML file, now I would like to display to users a specific product with description using id.

My XML file looks like this

[image]

Here is my js

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xxxxx",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            console.log(xml);
            var $xml = $(xml);
            item = $xml.find('item').has( "Id:contains('1215523')" );
            console.log(item);
        }
    });
```

Here is the result I get

[image]

What do I need to do to get what I need? any help or suggestions will be aprreciated

Comment: @JackFleeting I have provided a link on ajax request check it now

Comment: And what's your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting title, and desciption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `item g\\:id:contains('yourid')` to get information about particular `xml` node.

So your will look like :

```
  var $xml = $(xml);
  item = $xml.find('item g\\:id:contains("yourid")');
```

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(function() {
  var xml = "<rss version='2.0' xmlns:g='http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'>";
  xml += $("#xmldata").html();
  xml += "</rss>";
  //parse xml
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
  var result = "";
  //get item-><g:id>->1
  var pkSelector = "item g\\:id:contains('1')";
  console.log($xml.find(pkSelector).text());
  if ($xml.find(pkSelector).length > 0) {
    result = "<table border='1'>";
    result += "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Title</th><th>des</th></tr>";
    result += "<tr>";
    result += "<td>" + $xml.find(pkSelector).text() + "</td>";
    result += "<td>" + $xml.find(pkSelector).next("g\\:title").text() + "</td>";
    result += "<td>" + $xml.find(pkSelector).next("g\\:title").next("g\\:description").text() + "</td>";
    result += "</tr>";
    result += "</table>";
    $("#result").html(result);
  } else {
    $("#result").html("No item found  ");
  }


});
```

```css
#xmldata {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xmldata">
  <item>
    <g:id>
      1
    </g:id>
    <g:title>
      test
    </g:title>
    <g:description>
abcdjcdk
    </g:description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <g:id>
      2
    </g:id>
    <g:title>
      test2
    </g:title>
      <g:description>
    Sjdbvdvdvvvvvdsvsdv
    </g:description>
  </item>

</div>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: hej I get the id as you suggested then what about description?

Comment: just use `$xml.find('item g\\:id:contains("yourid")').next("g\\:title").next("g\\:description").text()`

Comment: Sorry i forgot you have one more node after id  try this to get description->`$xml.find('item g\\:id:contains("yourid")').next("g\\:gtin").next("g\\:title").next("g\\:description").text()` and to get title use ->`$xml.find('item g\\:id:contains("yourid")').next("g\\:gtin").next("g\\:title").text()`